# How to hide a div element whose class name changes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Before modal opens:

```
<div class="classname1">Some Text</div>
```

After modal closes:

```
<div class="classname1 classname2">Some Text</div>
```

Comment: please clear your question

Comment: Please provide the css code for classname1 and classname2

Answer (score 1):

You may refer my sample code.

```js
function addClass(){
 var div=document.getElementsByClassName("classname1")[0];
  div.classList.add('classname2');
}
```

```css
.classnam1{
  font-weight:bold;
}
.classname2{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="classname1">Some Text</div>
<button onclick="addClass()">
GO
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is not clear, assuming you want to add and remove the class on certain functionality.

I have created a sample fiddle using jQuery here [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/Arpit09/au5vc0Lp/9/)!

HTML

```
<div class="custCls" id="banner-message">
 <div>Hello World</div>
  <button id="addStyle">Add Style</button>
  <button id="removeStyle">Remove Style</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.custCls{
   width: 300px;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

jQuery

```
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $('#addStyle');
var button1 = $('#removeStyle');

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  banner.addClass("alt")
})

button1.on("click", function(){
  banner.removeClass("alt")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for new classnames by getting length of `classList` of elements.

First set initial length of `classList` of element and compare.

```js
var initiallen = 0;
var div = document.querySelector("div");
initiallen = div.classList.length;

function check(){
 return initiallen === div.classList.length ? false : true;
}
```

```html
<div class="classname1">Some Text</div>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('div').classList.add('classname2')">Add new classname</div>
<button onclick='console.log("class changed?" ,check())'>Check</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a custom attribute to that element and using it you can hide the element whenever required.

Html code.

```
<div class="classname" cust_attr="attr_1">Some Text</div>




Some Text
```

Jquery Code

```js
$("[cust_attr=attr_1]").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```